# Dockerfile - How to use 'echo' to dynamically generate variables OR expand IP ranges under ENV?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to add a whole CIDR IP ranges into "no_proxy" settings on my Dockerfile.
However, I couldn't get it to work. The echo command that I used `echo 10.144.192.{1..255} | sed 's/ /,/g'` isn't expanded by during the docker build.
I expect the IP to be expanded to 10.144.199.1,10.144.199.2,10.144.199.3....
The standard CIDR 10.144.199.0/24 doesn't work either, I think it's related to the OS I am using (Debian 10.8). Thanks in advance for any helps given.

Here is the result after I entered the container:
[image]

Here is my Dockerfile

```
FROM cypress/included:7.4.0

# add proxy info
ENV http_proxy http://10.166.30.88:8080
ENV https_proxy http://10.166.30.88:8080
RUN export http_proxy https_proxy

# add internal resource IPs
ENV no_proxy localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,10.100.206.90,10.172.154.251,ec.my.com.tw,mec.my.com.tw,`echo 10.144.199.{1..255} | sed 's/ /,/g'`
RUN export no_proxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ENV` keywork does not expand anything unfortunately.

The only solution is:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM cypress/included:7.4.0

# add proxy info
ENV http_proxy http://10.166.30.88:8080
ENV https_proxy http://10.166.30.88:8080
RUN export http_proxy https_proxy

# add internal resource IPs

ARG no_proxy
ENV no_proxy no_proxy

RUN export no_proxy
# and so on...
```

**Build script**

```
docker build \
  --build-arg no_proxy=localhost,127.0.0.0/8,::1,10.100.206.90,10.172.154.251,ec.my.com.tw,mec.my.com.tw,`echo 10.144.199.{1..255} | sed 's/ /,/g'` .
```